# Temporarly disable mouse click interactions on a Plotly plot ("freeze the plot")

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

With Javascript, **how to disable/enable all mouse interactions on a Plotly.js plot?** (click, drag and drop for selection or zooming, etc.)

This does not work: the interactions are still available on the plot, even after clicking the button:

```js
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [10, 15, 13, 17], mode: 'markers'}], {margin: {l: 50, r: 50, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 4}});


document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};
```

```css
#button { background: gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Click here to disable/enable interaction on plot</div>
<div id="container"><div id="myDiv"></div></div>
```

Comment: I suggest that you inside the button.onClick method set a bool which keeps track if the plot should be interactable. Then you need to check for the bool value inside your plotly_click/other event handlers https://plotly.com/javascript/click-events/

Comment: Another option is to have a look at the pointer events and try setting it to none for a parent element to your plot https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic This doesn't seem doable because I'm not coding the plotly_click/other event handlers myself when the plot is interactable. When the plot is interactable, every interaction is done internally by Plotly, and I don't use any event handler.

Comment: You can use the buttons to make the plot static. `Plotly.plot("myDiv", data, layout, {staticPlot: true});` and another button/event for `Plotly.plot("myDiv", data, layout, {staticPlot: false});` Just make sure the button is not within the Plotly scope.

Comment: @Kat Is there a way to change the config after the plot is done? I don't want to redraw the whole plot, but just change `staticPlot` to `true`. I know Plotly.restyle, Plotly.relayout, but it seems `Plotly.reconfig("myDiv", {staticPlot: false});` doesn't exist. How to do this?

Comment: You can use `Plotly.react('myDiv', data, layout, {staticPlot: true/false})`

Comment: @Kat Yes but when `data` is big, this will generate the rendering of the image, which is slow. How to change the config only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a native Plotly method to make this do what you want. However, I did come up with a workaround. I don't think it's particularly robust, but it does work.

Essentially there's an overlay that will cover the plot when static so that no pointer events work. When you make it interactive, it hides the overlay.

```js
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [10, 15, 13, 17], mode: 'markers'}], {margin: {l: 50, r: 50, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 4}});


document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};


function static() {
over = document.querySelector('#overlay');
over.style.display = 'block';
}
function interactive(){
over = document.querySelector('#overlay');
over.style.display = 'none';
}

stat = document.querySelector("#static");
inta = document.querySelector("#interactive");

stat.addEventListener('click', static);
inta.addEventListener('click', interactive);
```

```css
#button { background: gray; }
input {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #003b70;
color: white;
padding: 10px 50px;
margin: 10px;
z-index:10000;           /* always on top */
}
input:active { /* make it move */
position: relative;
top: 1px;
}
#overlay {
height: calc(100vh - 100px); /* below the buttons */
width: 100vw;
top: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1000;          /* above everything but the buttons */
display: none;
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Click here to disable/enable interaction on plot</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;"><input type="button" id="static" value="Make Plot Static"></input><input type="button" id="interactive" value="Make Plot Interactive"></input></div><div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="container"><div id="myDiv"></div></div>
```